# How do I optimize sql for reading multiple trees?

Tags: sql, tree, derby

I have a monitoring application which monitors calls which might have subcalls. So if I want to read the monitoring data, I want to get a list of calls including the subcalls. The calls might be nested indefinitely.

--START OF EDIT
In my current test table there are around 7 million entries. In productive usage it might be the doubled size. The children to be expected per root entry are from 0 to about 15, in very few cases there might be about 50 children. The hierarchy level is quite low, the maximum is around 5 levels.

Below is my approach of reading a limited amount of these entries with my datamodel. If you have any suggestions of improving the datamodel or the query, I'd love to hear from you.

END OF EDIT--

Basically, all forum entries I have found are about optimizing reading from one tree instead of multiple trees.

Currently, I have only one table like this:

```
create TABLE montest2
(
   rootId VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   messageId VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
   requestMessageId VARCHAR(45),
   sessionId VARCHAR(45),
   PRIMARY KEY (messageID)
);
```

The rootId is the same for all calls belonging to one tree.
If the sessionId has a value, we know it is a top level (root) call.
The messageId is unique to each call.
The requestMessageId will contain the parent's messageId.

Now I want to read the first 5 root calls including their children. I am able to do this using these statements:

EDIT: Please note that I narrowed down my problem to this query. I had an additional WHERE clause for reading the parents so that I am able to select different parents. But my tests showed that these were not responsible for the performance problems. (END OF EDIT).

1. Reading parents:

   SELECT am.messageId montest2 am (am.sessionID IS NOT null ) FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
2. Reading children:

   SELECT ac.messageId FROM montest2 ac
   INNER JOIN ( SELECT am.rootID 
                 FROM montest2 am
                 WHERE (am.sessionID IS NOT null )
                 FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY) parents
   ON ac.rootID = parents.rootID
   WHERE (ac.sessionID IS NULL);

I know that the second statement is not fast for many entries. Can anyone give me some advice how to optimize this query? Or what I should change about my datamodel?

PS: I am using Derby as a database, but it should work with any database - it would just imply changing the limit (fetch first x rows) syntax.

Comment: Adding an index on `rootId` should already make the query faster.

Comment: Good Suggestion. But I already have an index and it is still way too slow - any more tips?

Comment: Your data structure isn't really a tree

Comment: I agree, my structure is more like a forest.. :o) ..it is more a list of trees - is there a special name for such a structure?

Comment: you will always get the same 5 root entries - there is nothing to order the table

Comment: You're right. In order to simplify my query for an easier understanding I removed an additional "where" statement which limits my dataset to other 5 root entries. I've already identified them as not being the performance problem. I'll add this in the question.

Comment: Your update helps! - can nested children have a non null sessionId?

Comment: No, they can't. All the children have null as sessionId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem now as follows:

I've split up my single table with all entries into two tables. One table contains all root entries of the trees, the other one contains all children (and the children of the children and so on).
So the first query is done against the root table, the 2nd one against the children. Because the children table is only about quarter of size now, the query is way faster.
Also, I realized that one of my indexes was defined wrong so that it did not get into action. I realized this by an explain when I tried my problem on a db2 database using the db2 tools.

So, my tip for everyone out there: Keep your tables small and use explains to see if you're indexes are doing what they're supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why not move the join into the where clause, see if this is any better?

```
SELECT messageId 
FROM montest2
WHERE rootID in (
         SELECT rootID from montest2 
         WHERE sessionID IS NOT null 
         FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY ) AND 
      sessionID IS NOT null
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Unfortunately, it does not really make a difference performance-wise.
From the logical point of view it is clear that the query is getting slower and slower when I increase the limit in the subselect. But I can't think of a better idea...

Comment: I edited my question with the numbers and tried to explain what I want to achieve.